# How to create a Shared Query Folder using the vso-node-api (VSTS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In the VSTS Rest API, there's a piece of documentation showing me how to [create a folder](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#create-a-folder). Specifically, I would like to create a folder within the Shared Queries folder. It seems like I can do this with the REST API.

I would like to do the same thing with the VSTS Node API (`vso-node-api`). The closest analogous function I can seem to find would be `WorkItemTrackingApi.createQuery`. Is this the correct function to use?

When I try to use this function, I'm getting an error:

```
Failed request: (405)
```

That seems strange, since a "Method Not Allowed" error doesn't seem like the right error here. In other words, I'm not the person deciding what method (`GET/POST/...etc`) to use, I'm just calling the VSTS Node API's function which should be using the correct HTTP Request Method.

I think the error code would/should be different if something about my request is wrong (like providing bad parameters/data).

But, I would not be surprised if VSTS didn't like the data I provided with the request. I wrote the following test function:

```
async function createQueryFolder (QueryHeirarchyItem, projectId, query) {
  let result = await (WorkItemTrackingApi.createQuery(QueryHeirarchyItem, projectId, query))
  return result
}
```

I set some variables and called the function:

```
let projectID = properties.project // A previously set project ID that works in other API calls
let QueryHeirarchyItem = {
    isFolder: true,
    name: 'Test Shared Query Folder 1'
}
try {
    let result = await createQueryFolder(QueryHeirarchyFunction, projectID, '')
```

Notice that I provided a blank string for the query - I have no idea what to provide there when all I want to create is a folder.

So, I think a lot of things could be wrong with my approach here, but also if my request parameters are wrong maybe I should be getting a 400 error? 405 leads me to believe that the VSTS Node API is making a REST call that the underlying VSTS REST API doesn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third parameter of the `createQueryFolder`, you should **specify the folder path** where you want to create the new folder.

Such as if you want to create a folder `Test Shared Query Folder 1` under Shared Queries, you should specify parameters for `createQueryFolder` as:

```
let result = await createQueryFolder(QueryHeirarchyFunction, projectID, 'Shared Queries')
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work. I tried to edit the quotation marks in your answer to close them, but SO won't let me.